# Are these properties for independence false?

Tags: probability-theory

I have tried to prove that if:

> If $X$ is independent of $Y$, and $Y=Y_1+Y_2$, and $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are
>   independent. Then $X$ and $Y_1$ is independent.

But I am not able to prove this, but I can't find a counterexample either. I almost had it if the range of $Y_1$ was countable(because then I could split it up in a sum).

But in proving this, I used that:

> If $A$ and $B$ are independent, so that $P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$, then if $C$
>   is en event with $P(C)>0$, then $P (A\cap B\mid C)=P(A\mid C)P(B\mid C)$.

But this seems wrong by looking at the case:

[image]

So this last one is wrong? Do you know anything about the first one? I am not able to prove the first one, or find a counterexample. What I end up with is this:

I try to prove that $X$ and $Y_1$ is independent:

$P(X\in A, Y_1\in B)=P(X \in A, Y-Y_2 \in B)$. And then I try to use some sort of trick learned in elementary statistics where I in some way integrate over all possible values $Y_2$ can take. But I can't get the argument wo work correctly. Any hints or tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here is a counterexample, although not in $\mathbb{R}$:* take $X$ and $Y_2$ to be independent uniform random variables on $\{0,1\}$, and set $Y_1=X$.

Then $Y\stackrel{\rm def}{=}Y_1+Y_2 \mod 2$ is uniform on $\{0,1\}$ and independent of $X$, but clearly we do not have $X=Y_1$ independent of each other.

(If you want to remove the $\operatorname{mod} 2$ thing, just work in $\mathbb{Z}_2$.)